# How can I track a user at my affiliate website?

Tags: web, tracking

I am trying to build a website to support users to find the best bank account more easily.
So, I am planning to upload the bank information and have affiliation with those banks.
At this moment, I am thinking of guiding users to go to making bank account page of the banks.
I want to receive commission from the banks whenever new users have joined them through my website and they have actually made transaction.

My question is, how can I know if the user has made up the bank account through my website and actually made transaction?
Are there any ways on it except that the bank provides me the information regularly? 
I want to be able to track what the user does at the bank's website after being linked from my website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to track what the user does at the bank's website after being linked from my website.

I doubt that you'll find many (if any) banks that will allow you to track users on their website. And you can't do it without their consent.

You're putting the cart before the horse here. Before you start figuring out how to implement this, you need a partnership (affiliate program) with those banks. And from there, you'll need to play by their rules.

> Are there any ways on it except that the bank provides me the information regularly?

How else would you propose collecting and delivering this information?

If you want to pursue this, the best and least intrusive way to go about it is to have your partner banks set up referral codes or affiliate links; when customers come to them through you, the customers provide the affiliate code or click on a URL that's unique to you (provided on your website), and then the bank will report on the usage and pay out whatever has been agreed upon.

Comment: Alroc, thank you a lot for your response. I am new to make affiliation pages with other corporations, so my question was like a newbie. All in all, having a partnership and receiving reports from the banks would be the best. Thank you !